# CountdownTimer in a separate thread with looper

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, countdowntimer

I am trying to implement a countdown to warn users when they are exiting an area. To do this, I am attempting to use a CountdownTimer in a JobIntentService; however, this means the CountdownTimer is in a thread without a looper causing an exception to be thrown.
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread Thread[AsyncTask #1,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()`

I have found this [Question on a CountdownTimer in its own thread with looper](https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1154131/java/general-java/java-mobiles/android/thread-p-countdowntimer-p-handler/), but the answer there is 6-7 years old and I want to be using the best practices for threading and handlers.

If anyone could give a little insight into how to do this in a cleaner way, it would definitely be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Always create handler with the use of Looper.

**1) Creater UI handler** to update the UI

```
Handler mainThreadhandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
mainThreadhandler.post(new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
    // UI work
   }
});
```

**2) Create Thread handler**, to run the background task.

```
HandlerThread bgThread = new HandlerThread("MyHandlerThread");
bgThread.start();
Handler bgHandler = new Handler(bgThread.getLooper());
bgHandler.post(new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
    // background work
   }
});
```

Don't forget to cleanup while finishing the activity.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
  bgHandler.getLooper().quit();
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Will this work if I am updating text for a notification in a `JobIntentService`?

Comment: @AshesToAshes yes